# Маскирование фонов CSS

Tags: css, svg, background, clip-path

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите как реализовать маскирование фонов в CSS ? 
[image: пересечение фонов]

Необходимо добиться что б на выходе получить красный круг (5штук) с чёрным обводом. Эффект как-будто в диве с классом el дырка и через него просвечивает нижний фон. Я пробовал через clip-path но оно обрезает наружное, а мне надо то что внутри что б вырезало

```css
.block{
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.el{
   width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
/*    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
   clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="el">
    <svg>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А нельзя, например, вывести красные круги поверх черного фона?

Comment: Нет. Фон я задал для примера такой простой. На практике там может быть и сложный фон, и картинка и Бог знает что ещё

Comment: ну так вы можете сделать "круглые" `div` с фоном любой сложности

Comment: Могу, но это не решает поставленной задачи. ПС В детстве вообще, помню была такая игрушка, - Есть картинка с красивой тётей, водишь по ней биноклем, тетя раздевается. Как ренген очки 
Вообщем принцип где-то тот же.

Comment: Воот так надо было ставить задачу, про тёть сразу, а вы про круги, непонятно же. З.Ы. Надо подумать

Comment: Собственно, для этой задачи у меня то же самое "лобовое" решение - просто динамически менять `background-position` у нашего "красного круга". Вам такое не подойдет?

Comment: Тоже мимо. Не решает задачую Если этих кругов много. Мне уже предлагали  Перевести ту картинку с дыркой в ДиБейс64 и засунуть в ЦСС... но оно коряво смотрится

Comment: Если кругов много - считать для каждого отдельно

Comment: Вот как-то так https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/oo84tycz/

Comment: Спасибо, за эффект, интересно смотрится. Но это опять же немного не то меня интересует, реализация без подключение кода. CSS/SVG

Comment: Т.е. круги зафиксированы? Можно убрать js, поставить несколько кргуов, каждый со своим фоном и смещением фона

Comment: Это то все понятно. Задача изначально в том что б через форму можно б было видно нижний бекграунд родительского элемента

Comment: @br3t У меня в хроме черный квадрат Малевича

Comment: @Alexandr_T , котята битые попадаются, заменил картинку, обновите

Comment: @BlackStar1991 , вот вариант с вырезанной дыркой http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GroMPb , надеюсь, идея понятна. Делал тут http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Вот, что ты вспоминал? http://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/ByxQjL

Comment: @br3t Замечательно получилось у Вас.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А может попробовать маски для этой цели. Сделаем из  круга маску и сквозь нее будем смотреть на подложку. 
В первом варианте у меня красный квадрат подложка, а во втором растровое изображение.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"> 
<defs>
 <mask id="mask">
       <g stroke="gray" stroke-width="4" fill="white">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%"   />
      </g>
   </mask>
</defs>

 <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </g>
   </svg>
```

Теперь цветы. Фотка Yoksel и идеи её по использованию масок

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300"> 
<defs>
 <mask id="mask">
       <g stroke="gray" stroke-width="12" fill="white">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%"   />
      </g>
   </mask>
</defs>

 <g mask="url(#mask)">
   <image xlink:href="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6208/5091629.73/0_63193_9ffa75d7_L" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  </g>
   </svg>
```

Вот в качестве маски шестиугольник

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300"> 
<defs>
 <mask id="mask">
       <g  transform="scale(2.95) translate(18 0)" stroke="gray" stroke-width="4" fill="white">
        <path d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z" />
      </g>
   </mask>
</defs>

 <g mask="url(#mask)">
   <image xlink:href="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5106/yoksel.5a/0_44b5e_4da2ba62_orig" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  </g>
   </svg>
```

Отличная статья о масках от [Yoksel](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/)

Answer (score 3):

Такое ощущение, что недавно [отвечал](//stackoverflow.com/a/40994084/4928642) на такой же вопрос на SO.
Чёрная часть маски убирается из элемента, а белая остаётся:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red, blue);
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <mask id="circles" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="15" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="15" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="70" cy="80" r="15" fill="black" />
  </mask>
  
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" style="mask: url(#circles)" />
</svg>
```