# "Дырка" в родительском блоке CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, в общем проблема такова, есть фон - картинка, на нем есть блок с контентом, в нем еще блок для заголовка этой информации. Нужно сделать так, чтобы блок с заголовком был прозрачным и на нем был виден фон, при этом блок с инфой должен остаться белым(та часть, где нет заголовка). Можно пользоваться только css, погуглил - ничего не нашел

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели бы пример кода, того что у вас получается, и добавили бы картинку для наглядности.

Comment: Поиск: [`[css] дырка`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+дырка), более конкретно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731280/178988 & https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613156/178988

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то возможно [Вот так](https://codepen.io/kakabylik/pen/eVjYGb)

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://goodimg.ru/img/kartinki-ozero4.jpg);
}

.head {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.par {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="head">Заголовок</div>
    <p class="par">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi hic porro dignissimos laboriosam quae autem totam vel optio accusamus quo impedit iure illo culpa, aperiam sit, neque quod quisquam excepturi quis commodi minima provident nesciunt quos. Accusantium
      facilis et velit? Eius voluptates nobis quos earum nam aliquid expedita nesciunt, officia sit corrupti quas amet laboriosam similique dolore! In placeat, quod ducimus libero reprehenderit assumenda, harum debitis officia fugit accusantium corporis.
      Fugiat rem odit, in debitis provident, impedit amet culpa consequuntur deserunt sequi vero itaque cum et, assumenda odio est commodi cupiditate. Porro reprehenderit officia eaque nostrum numquam ab aliquid harum?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```